# Is Google's Friend Connect tool defunct?

Tags: google, social-networks

Looking at the Friend Connect sites, documentation, example, I've noticed that:

- there haven't been updates in a long time
- many of the sites used as example sites are dead or abandoned
- the community (forums, message boards, etc) is relatively silent

Is google's Friend Connect set of tools defunct/abandoned, or is it still actively being used, developed and marketed?

Comment: @Robert Harvey I'm unclear as to the reason this question was closed - please provide a comment explaining.

Comment: Sorry, @blueberryfields, I chose the wrong close reason. This question has the same problems as a long string of *"Is X technology dead"* questions; they are inherently subjective, and ultimately unanswerable, since any answer provided is going to be someone's opinion.

Comment: I'll migrate your question over to Programmers.SE; maybe it'll get a decent answer there.

Comment: `[untagged]`? Seriously?

Comment: How is this in any way related to programming?

Comment: @delnan: That's what happens when a question gets migrated and the tags don't match on the target site.  Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty dead over there. A few people do still use it... a big sign is that it never really even tried to integrate into gmail the way Yahoo or Windows Live did. They weren't very successful either but much much moreso by comparison.

I wish Google Wave had taken off..would have helped.